# Directshow MediaEvent GetEvent ErrorAbort Issue

Tags: directshow

running into an odd issue. Looking at the code below:

```
                    while (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                        while (mediaEvent.GetEvent(out ev, out p1, out p2, 0) == 0)
                        {
                            if (ev == EventCode.Complete || ev == EventCode.UserAbort)
                            {
                                tokenSource.Cancel();
                            }
                            else if (ev == EventCode.ErrorAbort)
                            {
                                Logger.Log(LogType.DEBUG, string.Format("An error occured: HRESULT={0:X}", p1));
                                tokenSource.Cancel();
                            }

                            mediaEvent.FreeEventParams(ev, p1, p2);
                        }
                    }
```

Once in a while (more than usual), ev will equal eventcode.errorabort when first starting however whats really throwing me off is p1 (which is an HRESULT) returns 0... meaning S_OK.

From what I understand is that I'm receiving a successful error... this is not intended.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what can cause a successful error... the graph starts up and runs fine and everything is successful until it gets into the while loop and eventually returns the successful errorabort.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some years ago.
Trying to figure out in the protocol and handshaking the folowing results (ev) were returned:

```
Error while synchronising data and player. = 0x40 
?    = 0x41 
?    = 0x42 
Moment, trying to connect...    = 0x43 
No internet access available or connection closed.    = 0x44 
The server is not responding or is not online.    = 0x45 
Moment, receiving data...    = 0x46 
?    = 0x47 
Connected with server.    = 0x48 
?    = 0x49
```

So far I tried to find these eventcodes in nserror.mc / _NSERROR_H but can't figure out in which header these results should be documented.